# lazy evaluation in Advanced R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

```
x_ok <- function(x) {
!is.null(x) && length(x) == 1 && x > 0
}

x_ok(1)
#> [1] TRUE
x_ok(1:3)
#> [1] FALSE
```

The desired behaviour is reached by combining the assertions through `&&` instead of `&`. `&&` does not perform elementwise comparisons. Instead, it uses the first element of each value only. It also uses lazy evaluation, in the sense that evaluation

> "proceeds only until the result is determined"

(from ?Logic)  (from advanced.R)

Lazy evaluation is for arguments not for the equations in function, But this sentence

> It also uses lazy evaluation, in the sense that evaluation "proceeds only until the result is determined"

say that evaluation done related to the content of the function. WHY???

Comment: what? I assume that sentence means it will stop and return false as soon as it hits a false, rather than working out everything

Comment: sentence not only say so but refer to lazy evaluation

Comment: What do you mean by "Lazy evaluation is for arguments not for the equations in function"? Lazy evaluation refers to evaluation of expressions, and the `&&` operator effects how the expressions are evaluated.

Comment: But in this chapter, "In R, function arguments are lazily evaluated" is written

Answer (score 1):

&& does not work elementwise but rather uses *short circuiting*.  The idea is that the RHS of && can be invalid if the LHS is FALSE but that is OK since the RHS is never evaluated in that case.  For example, the RHS here would generate an error if it were evaluated but it never is since the LHS is FALSE.

```
x <- "A"
is.numeric(x) && x + 1 < 0
```

If it did not work that way we would have to use the longer:

```
if (is.numeric(x)) x + 1 < 0 else FALSE
```